# Hibernate - How to bind parameter as nvarchar

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I got an oracle database, with a NVARCHAR2(2000 CHAR) field, the hbm file I have generated by hibernate reverse engineering is as below

```
<property name="remarks" type="string">
    <column length="4000" name="REMARKS" />
</property>
```

While update this file in database, I found it bind to varchar instead of nvarchar

```
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR]
```

If I enter 2000 Chinese characters, it will exceed its field length.

How can I make it bind to nvarchar instead?

**Update**

It is due to Oracle Database I am using. 

[Reference -](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/global.htm#CHDHHJDB) 
"By default, oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement treats all columns as CHAR."

**Solution**

Turn out I add defaultNChar to JNDI connection property

```
 <connection-property name="defaultNChar">
     true
 </connection-property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to Oracle Database I am using. 

[Reference -](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/global.htm#CHDHHJDB) "By default, oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement treats all columns as CHAR."

Turn out I add defaultNChar to JNDI connection property

```
 <connection-property name="defaultNChar">
    true
 </connection-property>
```

Comment: it's worth noticing that by this setting all the string columns are mapped to nvarchar2 instead of varchar2...

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify hbm file like this

```
<property name="remarks" type="string">
    <column name="REMARKS" sql-type="nvarchar(2000)"/>
</property>
```

Comment: Still the same  binding to varchar
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR]